# Does amazons3.listObjects(bucket,prefix) accept regex as a prefix to find objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can I use regex as a prefix in listobjects from amazons3 in Java aws sdk

Comment: No, the prefix is a prefix.

Answer (score 4):

As commenter @luk2302 already said, it is not possible.

The fact that you are trying to solve your problem with regex points to an interesting and often underestimated issue:

How to effectively model your data in S3.

S3 is commonly thought of as just a "disk in the cloud". But it is more like a database. Usually, we design our data in databases with relations etc. and use indexes. We create a data model based on the data we have and the way we want to access it.

You can do the same in S3.

You could think of the `prefix` as a kind of `index`. Everything that belongs together and you want to have fast access to should have the same prefix.

For example:

Imagine your application stores images. Furthermore, imagine you went on a nice vacation in France in 2019.

You could structure it like this (in terms of prefixes):

```
/images/2019_france
```

Now you would need to use a "regex" if you want all pictures taken in France :

```
/images/*_france
```

And as we know, that does not work. So if you find yourself often looking for pictures taken in a specific country, you probably should structure your data in S3 like this:

```
/images/france/2019
```

Now it is easy to find all the pictures taken in france by using the prefix:

```
/images/france
```

If you more often look for pictures by year, then maybe you need to structure your bucket like this:

```
/images/2019
```

I hope the point is clear:

**Prefix design is important when working with S3.**